# How to have clicking the phone's search button do nothing?

Tags: android

I'm trying to set up a screen so that when you click on the magnifying glass at the bottom of the phone it doesn't show the standard search area at the top of the screen: essentially, have it ignore (or catch it so I can do nothing) when the magnifying class is clicked on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the [onSearchRequested](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSearchRequested%28%29) method of [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) class:

```
public boolean onSearchRequested() {

        // Do whatever you want here.


        return true;
}
```

Comment: @charlest: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking on the small check mark left of it.

Comment: @NomanArain: Which version (and device) you are trying it on?

Comment: Android Version: 2.3.3, Sprint L5670 Optimus

Comment: I've tested it till Version 2.2. I don't have a 2.3 device with Search button for testing.