# How to start SearchActivity when clicked on edit text

Tags: android, searchactivity

I followed this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) for creating search interface.
But there was no proper explanation about how to start search activity when clicked on edit text but there is an explanation for only menu items.
My interface is in NoActionBarStyle as shown in below code and image

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="perspective.secretbrowser.MainActivity">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/menu_small"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/tabs_small"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/options"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/url_txt"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/url_bg"
            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/tabs"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.333"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarDeterminate
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/webView"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/progressBar" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[MainActivity.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSioM.png)

Suggest me code that will trigger searchactivity when clicked on edittext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found answer

set `onclicklistner` on `edittext` and trigger search activity using the `search(null,false,null,false)`

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13162436/android-how-to-disable-search-button-how-to-implement-onsearchrequested/13274280) for detailed explaination